# Hiding and showing divs by clicking image

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, show-hide

I'm trying to show and hide a div based on what image is clicked so when you click the resteraunt image it shows the div called members window. The error I'm getting is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`.

This is the script on a seperate JavaScript file

```
 $(document).ready(resteraunt(){

    $('people').click(function(){
    $("memberswindow").show();

    });

    });
```

Here is the HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html>

   <head> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
       <script src="Wolfeboro_Connection/Scripts/homepage.js"></script>
       <script src="Wolfeboro_Connection/Scripts/menu.js"></script>

   <link rel='stylesheet' href='Wolfeboro_Connection/CSS/index.css'> 


   </head>

   <body>



   <img src="Wolfeboro_Connection/wc.png" id="wc">

   <a href='' onclick='resteraunt();'><img src='Wolfeboro_Connection/resteraunt.jpg'        
   id="resteraunt"></a>
   <a href='' onclick='map();'><img src='Wolfeboro_Connection/map.jpg' id="map"></a>
   <a href='' onclick='mail();'><img src='Wolfeboro_Connection/mail.jpg' id="mail"></a>
   <a href='' onclick='people();'><img src='Wolfeboro_Connection/people.jpg' id="people"></a>

   <div id="window"> <div id="memberswindow"> <input type="text" id="username"   
   placeholder="Username">

   <input type="text" id="loginpassword" placeholder="Password">

   <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email"> </div> </div>

   <div id="banner"> <h1> Wolfeboro Connection </h1> </div>









   </body>

   </html>
```

Comment: Your jQuery selectors are missing the id hash.

Comment: just by looking at the "Related" answers column to the right this is clearly a duplicate question.

Comment: The function you pass to the `ready()` method is an anonymous function, not a named-function, which should be contained within the anonymous function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show one div while hiding other divs with jquery when clicking on links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673189/show-one-div-while-hiding-other-divs-with-jquery-when-clicking-on-links) just substitute the word "image" for "link"

Comment: restaurant is not spelled resteraunt. sorry i had to

Comment: duplicate? yes. shows initiative by posting and a willingness for constructive criticism after his own trial and error? yes.  isn't that what SO is all about? =/  I realize this is a pretty generic issue but I don't see the reason for all the yelling about duplication. As you ALL are very well aware, it takes time to build your personal referencing and research skills...I think we should encourage new posters to ask questions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jquery requires you to declare whether the target element is a "class" or an "id" by the denoting symbols "." and "#" respectively

try this:

```
$("#people").click(function(){
  $("#memberswindow").show();
});
```

also the syntax you are using for the document.ready() call is incorrect, try this as a full solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#people").click(function(){
      $("#memberswindow").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: the issue is you are calling the onclick="" attributes to your divs which is wholly unnecessary...you can remove the anchor (link) tags around your images.  jquery binds the click to the image element so there is no reason to put another html link around it

Comment: you can remove the <a> tags entirely.  there is no need for them when you are binding a click event to an element with jQuery

Comment: much thanks im at the jquery api should i be looking at the .bind and .click events

Answer (score 0):

you can't possibly create methods for different variations. Imagine when you have to show div for 100 different scenarios ?

A generic approach can be taken.

1. Create rel/class attribute for each entities

   ```
   <div id="ListenAllClick">
     <a href="#"><img src="mysrx" rel="divIdToShow"/></a>
     <a href="#"></a>
   </div>
   ```
2. Grab all anchor click events

   ```
   $(function() {  // equivalent to $(document).ready(function(){});

      $("a").on("click", function(eV) { 

         /* for better performance use 
             $("#ListenAllClick").on("click", "a", function() {});
             instead of 
             $("a").on("click", function() { 
         */
         eV.preventDefault();
         $("#" + $(this).attr("rel"/*"class"*/)).show();
      });
   });
   ```

Comment: wasnt me looks very complicated