# Show/Hide DIV's based on specific link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page that lists a series of content. I then have filters so someone can narrow down their search. I'd like to show/hide a block of information in my sidebar according to the filter that someone has clicked on. Basically clicking on a filter will show/hide these DIV's.

Here are two of the filters. Notice the one that is currently selected has an added class of “active” in two places.

```
<div class="container"> 
   <ul class="filters">
     <li class=“first active>
       <a class="filterbutton active" href="#filter">Category 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class=“last”>
       <a class="filterbutton" href="#filter">Category 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

When the page loads, Category 1 is active by default so I will show my corresponding DIV “block-1” by default.

Here is where the magic needs to be: When the filter link is clicked on above I would like to show/hide two DIV's that I have loaded.

```
<div id="block-1">content</div>    <—— Hide this one.

<div id="block-2">content</div> <—— Display this one.
```

It is also important that when a user clicks back on the first Category that it goes back to the default view of showing just the first block.

**UPDATE**: It took a long while but I finally figured it out. Using the "duplicate" answer here I tailored it to my needs. I also used some other code to add the necessary "rel" attributes that I needed.

Comment: Where's the javascript you've tried?  Have you searched? How about [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673189/show-one-div-while-hiding-other-divs-with-jquery-when-clicking-on-links)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know javascript so I am at the mercy of those that do. Thanks for the link. I had looked, but I guess missed that one. Thanks.

Comment: I just can't believe that you have searched for this and find nothing on internet.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović How about you say something constructive?

Comment: How about you read some rules before posting and SHOW something you have done or search this site before posting? http://stackoverflow.com/about More than 20% of questions and answers on SO is about jQuery and about show/hide divs.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible with simple js and CSS, however the hurdle will be in making it not look jarring. I would recommend using jQuery isotope. http://isotope.metafizzy.co. It isn't just for layouts, it also handles filtering quite nicely. If you don't need it for layout at all you could also use https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com

Comment: I tried isotope, but it just didn't work with the site that we have. So I was hoping that jquery could do some fade in/fade out.

Comment: it can but the effect is a bit janky. This is a basic demo of the process. http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/cd90a8b4470360d397bfa433a51883e1

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with toggle function : http://jsfiddle.net/AU8fX/1/

```
$( ".filterbutton" ).on( "click", function() {
    $('.block').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but the problem I am having with Toggle is that the user can click on the link again and it will be removed. I'd like it only to be removed when they click on another link.

Answer (score -1):

You say your JS isn't that good, let's see if I can give you enough clues:

```
<a class="filterbutton active" data-target="#example" href="#filter">Category 1</a>
```

Html5 has the data-group attributes. I wrote target, but you can put anything there, it can be for your just code.

You can get that when clicked:

```
$('.filterbutton').on('click', function(){
    // do something with the click
    alert( $(this).data('target') ); // I alert it, you van use this as a selector
}):
```

You can togglethe active class very easy with some code in the onclick:

```
$('.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

To show and hide elements:

```
$('.SomeElements').hide();
$( specific selector).show();
```

Comment: By the way: He's using the jQuery library in his answer - jquery.com

Comment: I'm not really sure wehat you mean with that comment, my code is jQuery isn't it? Or do you mean the `js` in the first sentence? jQuery is javascript aswell..

Comment: @Martijn Thanks for the clues. I am not able to add data-target to the link. I can only use what my CMS provides. I have created a jsfiddle above, but the show/hide is not working. If you can clue me in how to make that work I would appreciate it.